# openssl rsautl "unable to load Public Key"

Tags: openssl, pkcs#1

I generated an RSA public key in PKCS#1 `RSAPublicKey` format. I want to encrypt some data with `openssl rsautl` using this key, like so:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 512
Generating RSA private key, 512 bit long modulus
................++++++++++++
...++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
$ openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -RSAPublicKey_out -out public_key.pem
writing RSA key
$ echo "this is the cleartext" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -out encrypted_with_pub_key -pubin -inkey public_key.pem
unable to load Public Key
```

What is going on here? Why is `openssl` unable to read a key which it itself generated? What formats can it read? And more generally, why is this [so poorly documented](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Rsautl(1))?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** OpenSSL supports several legacy formats that are deprecated.  It seems there is a special case for `openssl rsa -pubout` when the input is an RSA private key pair.  At the end, I give two sequences of commands that let the OP's encrypt (and a corresponding decrypt) succeed; one by using DER rather than PEM, and another by first emitting DER, then converting it to PEM...strangely enough, using `openssl rsa`, which outputs the modern format when the input is a DER-encoded public key... go figure.  Anyway, below is a long description of why the OP's initial attempt failed.  As for "why so poorly documented"...welcome to OpenSSL.  Learn the source directory structure well, as it will speed up your grepping. :)

**A long explanation** (details taken from OpenSSL 1.0.2m)

The OpenSSL rsautl app defaults the `-inform` argument (incoming key representation) to `format = FORMAT_PEM`.

It then selects the reader for the incoming key using the format as follows:

```
else if (format == FORMAT_PEMRSA) {
    RSA *rsa;
    rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(key, NULL,
                                    (pem_password_cb *)password_callback,
                                    &cb_data);
    /* ... */
}
else if (format == FORMAT_PEM) {
    pkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(key, NULL,
                               (pem_password_cb *)password_callback,
                               &cb_data);
```

So, we'll be using `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY`.  Note the entry for `FORMAT_PEMRSA` above it...we'll develop the path that leads to `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey` at the same time.  Both of these readers are defined via a few macros

```
crypto/pem/pem_all.c:427:IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw(PUBKEY, EVP_PKEY, PEM_STRING_PUBLIC, PUBKEY)
crypto/pem/pem_all.c:241:IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw_const(RSAPublicKey, RSA, PEM_STRING_RSA_PUBLIC, RSAPublicKey)
```

Which expand to

```
# define IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw(name, type, str, asn1) \
    IMPLEMENT_PEM_read(name, type, str, asn1) \
    IMPLEMENT_PEM_write(name, type, str, asn1)

# define IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw_const(name, type, str, asn1) \
    IMPLEMENT_PEM_read(name, type, str, asn1) \
    IMPLEMENT_PEM_write_const(name, type, str, asn1)
```

That in turn use

```
# define IMPLEMENT_PEM_read(name, type, str, asn1) \
    IMPLEMENT_PEM_read_bio(name, type, str, asn1) \
    IMPLEMENT_PEM_read_fp(name, type, str, asn1)
```

Which builds the actual definition as:

```
# define IMPLEMENT_PEM_read_bio(name, type, str, asn1) \
type *PEM_read_bio_##name(BIO *bp, type **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u)\
{ \
  return PEM_ASN1_read_bio((d2i_of_void *)d2i_##asn1, str,bp,(void **)x,cb,u); \
}
```

Of particular note is the 3rd argument, `str` which is passed as `PEM_STRING_PUBLIC` for the `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` version, and as `PEM_STRING_RSA_PUBLIC` for the `PEM_read_bio_RsaPublicKey` version.  These strings are, respectively,

```
./crypto/pem/pem.h:122:# define PEM_STRING_PUBLIC       "PUBLIC KEY"
./crypto/pem/pem.h:124:# define PEM_STRING_RSA_PUBLIC   "RSA PUBLIC KEY"
```

Looking into the implementation of `PEM_ASN1_read_bio`, we see it calls `PEM_bytes_read_bio`

```
void *PEM_ASN1_read_bio(d2i_of_void *d2i, const char *name, BIO *bp, void **x,
                        pem_password_cb *cb, void *u)
{
    const unsigned char *p = NULL;
    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    long len;
    char *ret = NULL;

    if (!PEM_bytes_read_bio(&data, &len, NULL, name, bp, cb, u))
        return NULL;
    /* ... */
```

`PEM_bytes_read_bio` reads the key file, breaking it into portions. `nm` gets the marker between `-----` secions, e.g.,`-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`, which is then checked by `check_pem`.

```
int PEM_bytes_read_bio(unsigned char **pdata, long *plen, char **pnm,
                       const char *name, BIO *bp, pem_password_cb *cb,
                       void *u)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_INFO cipher;
    char *nm = NULL, *header = NULL;
    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    long len;
    int ret = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (!PEM_read_bio(bp, &nm, &header, &data, &len)) {
            if (ERR_GET_REASON(ERR_peek_error()) == PEM_R_NO_START_LINE)
                ERR_add_error_data(2, "Expecting: ", name);
            return 0;
        }
        if (check_pem(nm, name))
```

And `check_pem` checks as follows, where `nm` is the string found in the file, and `name` was passed from where it is hard-coded in the `PEM_read_bio_XXX` function.

```
static int check_pem(const char *nm, const char *name)
{
    /* Normal matching nm and name */
    if (!strcmp(nm, name))
        return 1;           

    /* special cases for
      PKCS8 format (BEGIN PRIVATE KEY or BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY)
      Various things ending in PARAMETERS
      Various X509 related files
      PKCS7 format (BEGIN PKCS7 or BEGIN PKCS7 SIGNED DATA)
      CMS things (BEGIN CMS) */

    /* ... */
```

It just does a `strcmp` between `name` and `nm`.  So, to successfully read the RSA public key with `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY`, it needs to start with `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`...but looking at the key produced by the OP's instructions, we find `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`.  But that's the string that corresponds to `PEM_read_bio_RsaPublicKey`...  Maybe we can use `-inform` to select `format = FORMAT_PEMRSA` instead, and get `rsautl` to read our public key that way.  `rsautl` uses a function called `str2fmt` to parse the `-inform` argument.  Let's take a look:

```
int str2fmt(char *s)
{
    if (s == NULL)
        return FORMAT_UNDEF;
    if ((*s == 'D') || (*s == 'd'))
        return (FORMAT_ASN1);
    else if ((*s == 'T') || (*s == 't'))
        return (FORMAT_TEXT);
    else if ((*s == 'N') || (*s == 'n'))
        return (FORMAT_NETSCAPE);
    else if ((*s == 'S') || (*s == 's'))
        return (FORMAT_SMIME);
    else if ((*s == 'M') || (*s == 'm'))
        return (FORMAT_MSBLOB);
    else if ((*s == '1')
             || (strcmp(s, "PKCS12") == 0) || (strcmp(s, "pkcs12") == 0)
             || (strcmp(s, "P12") == 0) || (strcmp(s, "p12") == 0))
        return (FORMAT_PKCS12);
    else if ((*s == 'E') || (*s == 'e'))
        return (FORMAT_ENGINE);
    else if ((*s == 'H') || (*s == 'h'))
        return FORMAT_HTTP;
    else if ((*s == 'P') || (*s == 'p')) {
        if (s[1] == 'V' || s[1] == 'v')
            return FORMAT_PVK;
        else
            return (FORMAT_PEM);
    } else
        return (FORMAT_UNDEF);
}
```

Nope.  There's no way to make it return FORMAT_PEMRSA.

Well, what if we edit the public key file to make the markers say `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` instead?

```
$ sed -e "s/RSA PUBLIC/PUBLIC/" public_key.pem > public_key_mod.pem             
$ echo "this is the cleartext" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -out encrypted_with_pub_key -pubin -inkey public_key_mod.pem
unable to load Public Key
```

Nope.

What if we extract the public key to DER instead of PEM?

```
$ openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -out public_key.der -outform DER -pubout
writing RSA key
$ echo "this is the cleartext" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -out encrypted_with_pub_key -pubin -inkey public_key.der -keyform DER

$ openssl rsautl  -decrypt -in encrypted_with_pub_key -inkey private_key.pem
this is the cleartext
```

Success!  Maybe we can get OpenSSL to convert the DER key into a form compatible with `rsautl`

```
$ openssl rsa -in public_key.der -inform DER -pubin -out test.pem
writing RSA key
$ cat test.pem
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAM3uGdU6YtwI5S8K+GgddW8KhrzmSFVI
6cvBT+XqOuSVo+n8VyUfADHw4rPxjy/dWDpyOxzWdTg8VZ77Vs06af8CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
$ echo "this is the cleartext" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -out encrypted_with_pub_key -pubin -inkey test.pem

$ openssl rsautl  -decrypt -in encrypted_with_pub_key -inkey private_key.pem
this is the cleartext
```

So yes...it looks like `openssl rsa` only writes the obsolete `BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY` form when it takes a `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` as input.